# How long must be the key of a stream cipher?

Tags: stream-cipher

I am watching [Lecture 3 (Stream cipher, random numbers and one time pad)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AELVJL0axRs) by Christof Paar and perhaps its something that will be explained in another lecture but:

When he explains how XOR works, in the example he gives, plaintext X3.X2.X1 is encrypted with key S3.S2.S1 and becomes ciphertext Y3.Y2.Y1.

So if the plaintext is N-bits long...the key has to also be N-bits long?

If the answer is no and it can be an arbitrary number...wouldn't that be a block cipher?

If the answer is yes, does the sending and receiver end have to agree on the quantity of bits to be transmitted beforehand?

If this is random (ie. unknown beforehand), how can they know what key to use to encrypt and unencrypt if it has to be as long as the plaintext?

Comment: You should continue to watch in order to escape from OTP. Look at ChaCha20 and Trivium to understand better.

Comment: @kelalaka But of course those don't have anyway near information theoretic security, and depend on not being broken now/next year/decade.

Comment: @PaulUszak Of course they don't have information theoretic security, but you don't _need_ information theoretic security. Not that I'd recommend Trivium for any serious security (and neither do its authors)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So if the plaintext is N-bits long...the key has to also be N-bits long?

Let's explain this point-by-point:

- The key *stream* has to be N-bits long for a stream cipher;
- For an OTP the key is basically the key stream;
- For a stream cipher or block cipher (in stream mode such as counter mode) the key is generally between 128 and 256 bits to be considered secure;
- For these ciphers the key is used to generate the key stream.

I've skipped "plaintext aware" stream ciphers as they don't use XOR (directly) to calculate the ciphertext from the key and plaintext.

> If the answer is no and it can be an arbitrary number...wouldn't that be a block cipher?

A block cipher is a cipher that permutes one  block of plaintext to a block of ciphertext (and vice versa) - using the key to select the permutation. You can have block ciphers and stream ciphers with about any size of key. The key size doesn't define if something is a stream cipher or block cipher.

> If the answer is yes, does the sending and receiver end have to agree on the quantity of bits to be transmitted beforehand?

The answer is no, so that makes this question invalid. Nevertheless: for an OTP you'd have to make sure that you know the location within the key stream and of course that you have shared enough key bits. For a stream or block cipher you don't need to know the quantity of bits to be transmitted beforehand. However, you should be using a unique IV or nonce for each message.

> If this is random (ie. unknown beforehand), how can they know what key to use to encrypt and unencrypt if it has to be as long as the plaintext?

They use a complex technique called "keeping count" :) And yes, it is a problem if the index gets out of sync, e.g. because of lost messages.

Answer (score 1):

There is a key expansion procedure, whereby a long key is derived from a shorter truly random key. The entropy of the long key is not increased, i.e., the long key is not truly random. This is why it is often called a pseudokey. Perfect security is no longer feasible. For computational security, the pseudokey needs to be computationally indistinguishable from a truly random key.

Answer (score 1):

> So if the plaintext is N-bits long...the key has to also be N-bits long?

Not really. The following is a **real** Stasi OTP that is 250 digits long i.e. the key is a fixed size irrespective of the message length. As long as it fits:-

[image: otp]

This is how it was done for decades and decades. And it worked very well. And it can be done this way today. 8K UHD movies should not be sent encrypted with OTPs. That's not what OTPs are for! Newer is not always better.

> for an OTP you'd have to make sure that you know the location within the key stream

As long as you bear the above in mind, there's no need to keep count of the character position. Simply discard the entire OTP when it's used; equivalent to eating the page above. 10,000 messages each the size of ten tweets is only 28 MB. That's nothing for today's hardware, both storage wise and DIY TRNG wise. This technique also allows bidirectional 1 to N messaging from a single key set as long as each 2800 byte OTP has a unique(ish) id number/filename. And you can always use another pad for more chat. Also bear in mind that a OTP was typically used with a [codebook](https://www.cryptomuseum.com/crypto/codebook/index.htm). That means the size of the semantic plaintext can be much much bigger than the key itself.

> If this is random (ie. unknown beforehand), how can they know what key to use to encrypt and unencrypt

Because you send the pad id first in the clear, which they did historically. Today that would be the filename, say a truly random 256 bit one.